# Force one tab in Chrome

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, tabs

Does Google Chrome have a way to force links to open in a new window instead of a new tab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> will open the link in new Window.

Comment: Thanks! I use Chromium, so it's good to know that when using fullscreen mode.